# how to prevent output volume popping back to 100%

Tags: volume-control, headset

The output volume in Ubuntu normally can go up to 100% unamplified. It is possible to go beyond this to amplified levels using settings in the interface of `gnome-control-center sound`. However, when a standard volume control on a keyboard or headset is used, the volume pops back down from the amplified region - making the amplified region inaccessible by these normal controls. So, for example, let's say I have the following settings:

[image: gnome-control-center sound]

In this configuration, if I now select the volume up option on my headset, the volume *decreases* to the 100% level. This is counter-intuitive for me. How can I prevent this behaviour from occurring? I would like to have this full range accessible to me using the normal controls on my keyboard, headset etc. Thanks for any ideas!